# How can I move linked turtles to the location of one of the linked turtles in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I created a model with turtles which are organized in groups with links.

Now I want to move all linked turtles of this "group" to the position of one member (can be random) of the group.

I tried different ways but the result was not what I wanted to do. This is what I tried:

```
breed [AT1 AT1_1]
turtles-own [home-location]

to meet
   ask AT1 [
   let group-home one-of [home-location] of link-neighbors
   move-to get-home
```

Is it possible to do this with links or should/can I generate also groups as a turtles-own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are doing something really fancy,  the position of each turtle is already always owned as variables xcor and ycor.   You don't need to make a new variable home-location.

So if you just want all the turtles in AT1 to converge on where one of them is now,  this would work:

```
to meet
  let target one-of AT1
  ask AT1 [ 
     move-to target   
   ]
end
```

Note that setting the target is OUTSIDE the "ask ATI" loop or you will not get what you are after.

If you really have "home-location" for each turtle that may be different from where it is located now,  then it needs to be a list of the x-coordinate and y-coordinate, or you need two variable like home-location-x and home-location-y .

If you do that, then this would be work as meet code;

```
to meet2
  let target one-of AT1
  let tx [home-location-x] of target
  let ty [home-location-y] of target
  ask AT1 [ setxy  tx ty ]
end
```